# Overriding method in separate instantiated class

Tags: kotlin, inheritance, design-patterns, overriding, decorator

There are 2 classes inherited from parent:

```
abstract class Parent{
    abstract fun prepare()
    abstract fun act()
}

class Child1:Parent(){
    fun prepare()
    fun act()
}
class Child2:Parent(){
    fun prepare()
    fun act()
}
```

I need to modify only method act() just to perform some action before it and run it after:

```
class Modify (parent:Parent):parent{
    override fun act(){
        ...//modification
        parent.act() //from Child1 or Child2 depends 
    }
}

class Modify1 (parent:Parent):parent{}
class Modify2 (parent:Parent):parent{}
```

The idea is to have several modificators and use them arbitrarily both for modified and not modified instances along with using several serial modificators:

```
val modifiedChild1:Parent = Modify1 ( Modify3( Child1() ) )
val modifiedChild2:Parent = Modify1 ( Child2() )
val notModified1:Parent   = Child1 ()
```

Please advise if this concept is correct and how to implement it. Thanks.

the only way I found: is to add an interface as listener.
But in that case, it is not possible to use Modify() as a function and possibility perform several modifications.

Comment: This sounds like aspect oriented programming to me - with inheritance alone you can't do that. Maybe you also want to implement the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) but from your description of how to do it I cannot really tell if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in modifying the *public* functions of Parent, you can use the Decorator pattern to create a wrapper class and override the functions. For example:

```
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

abstract class Parent {
   abstract fun prepare()
   abstract fun act()
}

class ParentDecorator(val parent: Parent): Parent() {
   override fun prepare() {
      // modification
      parent.prepare()
      // modification
   }
   override fun act() {
      // modification
      parent.act()
      // modification
   }
}

class Child: Parent() { ... }

val child = Child()
val decoratedChild = ParentDecorator(child)
decoratedChild.prepare()
   // will call the modifications around the call to the 
   // nested child instance
```

This only works if the parent is abstract, open, or is an interface, and only affects the public functions that you override in the Decorator.

Note - this example is a tad awkward - we're creating an instance of Parent to override all of its functions and *wrap* another instance of Parent, delegating the real function to that wrapped instance. It would be *much* better to make Parent an interface if you want to create a Decorator. For example:

```
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

interface Stuff {
   fun prepare()
   fun act()
}

class StuffDecorator(val realStuff: Stuff): Stuff {
   override fun prepare() {
      // modification
      realStuff.prepare()
      // modification
   }
   override fun act() {
      // modification
      realStuff.act()
      // modification
   }
}

class Child: Stuff { ... } 
   // could extend another class that implements Stuff

val child = Child()
val decoratedChild = StuffDecorator(child)
decoratedChild.prepare()
   // will call the modifications around the call to the 
   // nested child instance
```

However, if you're stuck with an existing open/abstract Parent class, this is the best you can do)

If you want to do this is non-public functions, @cyberbrain's mention of AspectJ is more the way to go (but I'm not sure that can work with Kotlin - I see some mentions, such as https://github.com/serpro69/kotlin-aspectj-maven-example/blob/master/README.md, but no idea if that actually works).